# WPF TreeView DataTemplate binding with non-nested class problem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to set up a tree view for my situation based on [this](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/)example, but the difference is my classes are not nested inside the UserControl class, but in a separate namespace - .DataModel. I can't get it working, either I get build error stating that:

- "The name "TypeInfo" does not exist in the namespace
  "clr-namespace:SegmentDataUpdater.DataModel".    SegmentDataUpdater  SegmentDataUpdaterDialog.xaml"

Or I get the list with TypeInfo type description in the dialog. What am I doing wrong?

My current code is (it gives the build error):

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SegmentDataUpdater.GUI.SegmentDataUpdaterDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SegmentDataUpdater.GUI"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:SegmentDataUpdater.DataModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Segment Data Update" Height="450" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <TreeView Name="trvTypeInfos">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:TypeInfo}" ItemsSource="{Binding SegmentInfos}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SegmentInfos.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                    <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:SegmentInfo}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" (" Foreground="Green" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HasData}" Foreground="Green" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" years)" Foreground="Green" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
namespace SegmentDataUpdater.GUI
{
public partial class SegmentDataUpdaterDialog : Window
{
    public List<TypeInfo> TypeInfoList { get; set; }

    public SegmentDataUpdaterDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        TypeInfoList = new List<TypeInfo>();

        TypeInfo type1 = new TypeInfo() { Name = "Typ pierwszy"};
        type1.SegmentInfos.Add(new SegmentInfo() { Name = "Segment 1", HasData = true });
        type1.SegmentInfos.Add(new SegmentInfo() { Name = "Segment 2", HasData = false });
        TypeInfoList.Add(type1);

        TypeInfo type2 = new TypeInfo() { Name = "Typ drugi" };
        type2.SegmentInfos.Add(new SegmentInfo() { Name = "Segment 1", HasData = true });
        TypeInfoList.Add(type2);

        trvTypeInfos.ItemsSource = TypeInfoList;
    }
}
}
```

TypeInfo class:

```
namespace SegmentDataUpdater.DataModel
{
    public class TypeInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<SegmentInfo> SegmentInfos { get; set; }

        public TypeInfo()
        {
            SegmentInfos = new ObservableCollection<SegmentInfo>();
        }
    }
}
```

Added in edit:

SegmentInfo class:

```
namespace SegmentDataUpdater.DataModel
{
    public class SegmentInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool HasData { get; set; }
        public string JsonContents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the TypeInfo class defined in the same project/assembly as the window itself? Do you have any other build errors?

Comment: @mm8 It's in the same assembly but a different folder. I've got the same error as described to both: TypeInfo, and SegmentInfo.

Comment: And both are in the SegmentDataUpdater.DataModel namespace? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: @mm8 I updated the question with SegmentInfo class declaration, and namespace of the Window class. I'm not very fluent in WPF so I assume it's just a matter of wrong xaml syntax. The other syntax I tried was: <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="data:TypeInfo" ItemsSource="{Binding SegmentInfos}"> . Then I don't get build errors, but the tree view doesn't list me the objects but two lines of "SegmentDataUpdater.DataModel.TypeInfo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. The problem was with configuration settings.

The project was set to x64 but configurations for any cpu, after setting configuration to x64 it works.

Working solution in my [second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276093/wpf-changes-in-treeviewitems-properties-not-reflected-in-ui-problem) about another problem.